# react-native app crashes without log on Firebase auth logout when using 'onSnapshot' with 'where' query and 'in' operator

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

The title pretty much says it all. On the home screen, I subscribe to a list of categories using the following code:

```
export const subscribeToCategories = ({categoriesList, limit },
  callback
) => {
  try {
    return eventsRef
      .where('startDate', '>=', now)
      .where('categoryID', 'in', categoriesList)
      .orderBy('startDate', 'asc')
      .limit(limit)
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const newStart = querySnapshot?.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]
        const data = []
        if (querySnapshot?.size){
          querySnapshot?.forEach(doc => {
            const event = doc.data()
            data.push({ ...event, id: doc.id })
          })
        }
        callback({ eventsData: data, newStart })  
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Could not subscribe: ", err)
    }
}
```

The function is called on the home screen through `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (categoriesList.length === 0 || !limit || !categoriesLoaded) {
      return
    }
    categoriesUnsubscribe.current = eventsAPI.subscribeToCategories( {categoriesList, limit}, onEventsUpdate)

    return () => {
      categoriesUnsubscribe?.current && categoriesUnsubscribe?.current()
    }
  }, [categoriesList, limit, categoriesLoaded])
```

I've confirmed that if I comment out the line of code in the subscribe function with `.where('categoryID', 'in', categoriesList)`, the app does not crash upon logout. I've added a condition in the `if` statement to make sure the function doesn't run if the list is empty, and a `try/catch` block and it still crashes. There are no logs. I'm really stumped.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

** Edit to add current versions and more info **

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^16.4.6",
   "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.23.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.4",
```

Although it won't suit my needs, I created a new array field for `categoryID` and tried using `array-contains-any`. It does work without crashing, but I need to use `in`. For now, I'm keeping the `where`/`in` line commented out and filtering on the client side, but it would be great to have an answer for this.

Comment: If this is a bare React Native app, try crashing the app from Android Studio or Xcode - you will get better logs

Comment: Have you tried `array-contains-any`. you can also check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya categoryID isn't an array though

Comment: @Abe I thought it wasn't crashing on Android, but I must have tested with the where in clause commented out, because it is indeed crashing on Android too. There is no log for the crash on Android studio or Xcode.

Comment: Are you building and running the app through Android Studio/Xcode?

Comment: @Abe yes that's correct

Comment: What happens when it  crashes? Are you looking at the logs/ console?

Comment: Yes, there's no log output that I can see on Android Studio. On Xcode there's just 
```App(46356,0x318d58000) malloc: *** error for object 0x600003ec99c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
App(46356,0x318d58000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue was already reported [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10507) and the solution is listed [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6725#issuecomment-1342808185). The solution currently is to manually override your version locally in Podfile by placing `$FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.3.0'` at the top of your Podfile.